# Export to excel from asp.net c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I am trying to export the data table to the excel sheet in asp.net mvc. I tried the following code to export. It does't show any errors but it does't create the excel file also. So what is the problem in this code?

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string filename = "DownloadMobileNoExcel.xls";
                    System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                    DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                    dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    dgGrid.DataBind();

                    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

                    this.EnableViewState = false;
                    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                    Response.End();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The process is explained in detail in this post: [Export DataSet and DataTable to Excel 2007 in C#](http://bytesofcode.hubpages.com/hub/Export-DataSet-and-DataTable-to-Excel-2007-in-C)

Comment: Microsoft does not recommend you use those Excel functions to create Excel files in ASP.NET